# GET error on loading .css and .js files from server

Tags: javascript, html, css

I need some help. I am working on the web page based on prestashop. 
I've done everything on the local server on my machine.

Everything worked correctly. I decided to public the page so I move to the server.

**When I open the page with chrome or other browser It looks very bad.**

I checked the console and I've got some errors like this:

```
boston-armatura.pl/:26
GET http://boston-armatura.pl/new/themes/boston/assets/css/mystyle.css 
boston-armatura.pl/:28 
GET http://boston-armatura.pl/new/themes/boston//assets/css/theme.css
```

There is quite a long list. 
I tried to change privileges. 
I am also sure that the path is correct.

what might be the problem?

Comment: have you checked cross origin is allowed? and please post relevant code that makes the call, not only a error message that tells us nothing

Comment: Mentioning Operating System and Web Server will also help?

Answer (score 0):

The server is not allowing you to access those files maybe due to some configuration you might have made on your `.htaccess`(webconfig) file.

And that's why it is giving a 403 error.

If there are errors, edit your `.htaccess` file which this:

```
Options -Indexes
```

This will deny access to just the directories and no js, css and any other files.